# In terraform plan output was does number at end of AWS resource ARN mean?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am updating an existing terraform deployment by adding a new tag to all resources.  This is what the terraform plan output shows:

```
# module.fargate_ecs.aws_ecs_service.my_fargate_service_f490_c034 will be updated in-place
~ resource "aws_ecs_service" "my_fargate_service_f490_c034" {
      id                                 = "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:012345678:service/connect-cluster-prod/connect-service-prod"
      name                               = "connect-service-prod"
      tags                               = {}
    ~ tags_all                           = {
        + "Portfolio"   = "Digital Support"
          # (5 unchanged elements hidden)
      }
    ~ task_definition                    = "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:012345678:task-definition/connect-task-prod:101" -> "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:012345678:task-definition/connect-task-prod:90"
      # (14 unchanged attributes hidden)

      # (4 unchanged blocks hidden)
```

Notice in the `~ task definition` line the ARNs have the numbers 90 and 101 at the end of the ARNs.  What do those numbers mean?

Comment: IIRC, that's task definition revision number.

Comment: Thanks, does this `terraform plan` output mean the ECS task definition would go back from revision 101 to revision 90?  If so, why would adding a new tag cause that to happen?

Comment: Yes it indicates you are going to roll back the task definition from version 101 to version 90. This is mostly likely because you have been creating new task definition versions outside of Terraform, and version `90` is the last one that was in the Terraform state.

Comment: Thanks, that make sense and explains well what has happened.